# How to search a key in JSON Object if format is not constant?

Tags: android, json

In my android application, I have saved my form's data in a json, the parent of this json is a json object that may contains simple key value pairs, or a JSON Array, or sub json object.

The structure of Parent JSON Object is basically changing on run time and i have to add a function that can find value saved against any key.

For example, if I have the following JSON and I want to get value of `key5`. Is there any way to get the value?

A solution that i want to try is loop through the json but i am unable to check what is stored on index of json object mean is it a simple string, a json array or a sub json object.

```
{
    "key1": "value of key 1",
    "key2": "value of key 2",
    "key3": "value of key 3",
    "subjson": {
        "key4": "value of key 4",
        "key5": "value of key 5",
        "key6": "value of key 6"
    },
    "subjsonArray": [
        {
            "key7": "value of key 7",
            "key8": "value of key 8"
        },
        {
            "key9": "value of key 9",
            "key10": "value of key 10"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can someone please help me out with this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to handle json

```
    JsonElement jsonElement = new Gson().fromJson("YOUR JSON", JsonElement.class);
    if(jsonElement.isJsonObject()){
        jsonElement.getAsJsonObject("key5");
    }else if(jsonElement.isJsonArray()){
        jsonElement.getAsJsonArray("key5");
    }
```

If you need to iterate over json you can use

```
Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = jsonObject.entrySet();
for(Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry : entrySet){
    String key = entry.getKey();
    JsonElement value = jsonObject.get(entry.getKey()));
}
```

You need to import Gson to your project

```
    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    }
```

More information how to use Gson:

```
https://github.com/google/gson
```

Comment: How's this going to find the `key5` inside the `subjson`?

Comment: I edited the answer to make this possible. Thank you to point that.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying this - you should try to fix the non-constant Json issue before finding a solution for this.

But if it's out of your control, here's what might work.

This handles nested `JsonObject` and/or `JsonArray`.

You can just copy/paste those functions.
All you have to do is call this function - `getValueFromNonConstantJson(...)`

```
private void getValueFromNonConstantJson(String fullJson, String key) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    final Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();

    Map<String, Object> objectMap = gson.fromJson(fullJson, mapType);
    String value = "";

    value = getValueFromMap(objectMap, key);
}


private String getValueFromMap(Map<String, Object> objectMap, String key) {
    String result = "";

    // let's quickly check is the root object contains the key you want
    // if it does, you don't have to start the for loop at all
    if(objectMap.containsKey("key5")) {
        Object key5Value = objectMap.get("key5");
        if(key5Value instanceof JsonObject) {
            JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) key5Value;
            result = getValueFromJsonObject(jsonObject, key);
        } else if (key5Value instanceof JsonArray) {
            JsonArray jsonArray = (JsonArray) key5Value;
            result = getValueFromJsonArray(jsonArray, key);
        }
    } else {
        for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : objectMap.entrySet()) {
            if(entry.getValue() instanceof JsonObject) {
                JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) entry.getValue();
                result = getValueFromJsonObject(jsonObject, key);

                if(!result.isEmpty()) {
                    // you found it.
                    break;
                }

            } else if (entry.getValue() instanceof JsonArray) {
                JsonArray jsonArray = (JsonArray) entry.getValue();
                result = getValueFromJsonArray(jsonArray, key);

                if(!result.isEmpty()) {
                    // you found it.
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}


private String getValueFromJsonObject(JsonObject subJsonObject, String key) {
    String value = "";

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    final Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();

    Map<String, Object> objectMap = gson.fromJson(subJsonObject, mapType);

    value = getValueFromMap(objectMap, key);
    return value;
}


private String getValueFromJsonArray(JsonArray subJsonArray, String key) {
    String value = "";

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Object[] objectArr = gson.fromJson(subJsonArray, Object[].class);

    for(Object object : objectArr) {
        if(object instanceof Map) {
            Map<String, Object> objectMap = (Map<String, Object>) object;
            value = getValueFromMap(objectMap, key);

            if(!value.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JSONObject a possible implementation can be

```
 private Object interateNestedJson(JSONObject jsonObject, String keySearch) {

        for (Iterator<String> it = jsonObject.keys(); it.hasNext(); ) {

            try {
                String jsonKey = it.next();
                Object jsonValue = jsonObject.get(jsonKey);

                if (jsonValue instanceof JSONArray) {
                    Object foundInArray = iterateArray((JSONArray) jsonValue, keySearch);
                    if(foundInArray != null) {
                        return foundInArray;
                    }

                } else if (jsonValue instanceof JSONObject) {
                    Object foundInObject = interateNestedJson(jsonObject, keySearch);
                    if(foundInObject != null) {
                        return foundInObject;
                    }

                } else {
                    return jsonValue; // return primitive value
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

```
private Object iterateArray(JSONArray jsonArray, String keySearch) throws JSONException {
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            Object jsonObject = jsonArray.get(i);
            if (jsonObject instanceof JSONObject) {
                Object inNested = interateNestedJson((JSONObject) jsonObject, keySearch);
                if (inNested != null) {
                    return inNested;
                }
            } else if (jsonObject instanceof JSONArray) {
                Object inArray = iterateArray((JSONArray) jsonObject, keySearch);
                if (inArray != null) {
                    return inArray;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And you start the search like this

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
Object value = interateNestedJson(jsonObject, "key5");
```

I have no time to test this now, if it has an error I'll try to fix it later

Answer (score 0):

Using Retrofit, you can achieve it like this :

Below is the **Model** class which extends **JsonElement** as the **JsonResponse** structure is undefined

```
public class JsonResponse extends JsonElement {

    //Key will be of type JsonElement
    @SerializedName("key1")
    public JsonElement key1;

    //Return type is JsonElement since it is decided at Runtime
    public JsonElement getKey1() {
        if (key1 instanceof JsonArray) {
            List<JsonObject> objectList = getArray(key1);
            return (JsonElement) objectList;            //If key is of type JsonArray then return JsonArray
        } else {
            return getObject(key1);                      //If key is of type JsonObject then return JsonObject
        }
    }

    public void setKey1(JsonElement key1) {
        this.key1 = key1;
    }

    private JsonObject getObject(JsonElement data) {
        Type type = new TypeToken<JsonObject>() {}.getType();
        return new Gson().fromJson(data, type);
    }


    private List<JsonObject> getArray(JsonElement data) {
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<JsonObject>>() {}.getType();
        return new Gson().fromJson(((JsonObject) data).get("key1"), type);
    }

    //Method from super class
    @Override
    public JsonElement deepCopy() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Same process can be repeated for the `keys` whose return-type is not defined. 
Then in your `ClassA` you can fetch data by directly accessing `key1` element from `JsonResponse` class.

In your `ClassA`, check if this element `key1` is of type `JsonArray` or not and fetch data accordingly.